# How to speak to Parse server with azure using unity?

Tags: c#, azure, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

So we are using **Azure** and we set up a "**parse server managed aZure service** - web and mobile"
we are not using the prefab parse initialize script but rather this as suggested in the doc under .net

```
// Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


            ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration {
                ApplicationId = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
                Server = "https://servername/parse/"
            });

        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject["foo"] = "bar";
        testObject.SaveAsync();
    }
```

But nothing happens. no row is created.

Can anyone please assist?

thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't be using parse for any of your work at this because it is shutting down on January 28, 2017. You need to find an alternative of Parse service. What Unity version are you using? Also did you check for new created stuff anything on the Data Browser in your app on Parse?

Comment: Luke do you mean Parse as in Parse.com?

Comment: if you have your own instance of Parse somewhere (on Heroku or whatever). In the first instance login to the back end (I mean the www backend of "your" Parse) and make a screen shot of the project in question and show it here (click edit to add image)

Comment: @JoeBlow We had a working one yesterday, i cannot give you a screen shot right now because i deleted the server and started a new one. but today the new server looks completely different to the one of yesterday. the index.js file is completely different. Ah man yesterday i at least had the dashboard working...

Comment: @Programmer we are using parse server on azure. parse recently made there entire server open source. so that we can build our own parse servers.

Comment: @Programmer you know it does seem to work quite well if you have a Parse instance on (say) Heroku.  Unfortunately (a) I am not familiar with Azure as such and (b) I am the world's most hopeless sysadmin, I need experts to start my Mac in the morning to check email  :O  I do know that if you have a team of expert server folks you can get Parse running well on some sort of cloud/metal situation!